# C# post chunks of ids and merge response using async and await

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing a method which accepts a list of IDs to call an API.
The API has a limit that it only accepts 1000 IDs at a time. So I need to split the list into chunks and make separate calls.

```
public async Task<List<JObject>> readData(List<int> IDs){
    const int APIMaxLimit = 1000;
    List<List<int>> chunks = new List<List<int>>();
    while (IDs.Any())
    {
        chunks.Add(IDs.Take(APIMaxLimit).ToList());
        IDs= IDs.Skip(APIMaxLimit).ToList();
    }
    var apiCallTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var chunk in chunks)
    {
        //some logic
        apiCallTasks.Add(ReadDatacentersFromResponse(response));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(apiCallTasks);

    //What do I return?

}

private static async Task<List<JObject>> ReadDatacentersFromResponse(HttpResponseMessage response);
```

I wrote the above code, but I don't know how to return the combined values. Also, is there a way to write more elegant code without using for loop?

Comment: @zzxyz I'm not really seeing anything super complicated about his question. While it uses `async`/`await`, the answers he needs are not directly related to it.  It could all be simplified down to splitting a list of numbers in to batches and then recombining them without really changing much.

Comment: @zzxyz that seems a bit knee-jerk and unhelpful to me. The OP doesn't need to make any "`Run()` calls" to make his/her code work. He/she has a legitimate question about how to combine the results of tasks he/she is awaiting with the `Task.WhenAll` call.

Comment: He doesn't?  His tasks will just run themselves?  What am I missing?  And I'm guessing the problem is he doesn't know how to check the return values from a Task.  If that's not the problem, `.AddRange()`.  Done.  I'm not trying to be a jerk, just saying a problem like this is not a good place to learn the async pattern.  The web server could be down or one of a hundred other problems could complicate the issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm just straight up wrong here, though, and the syntax he is using DOES run the tasks?

Comment: @zzxyz He probably just left out a line of code to run the task when he simplified his code for posting.  Either way, it isn't relevant to merging the results back together.

Comment: I don't understand how not having results is irrelevant to using them.

Comment: @zzxyz The only tasks included in the question are those returned from `ReadDatacentersFromResponse` which are awaited in the `Task.WhenAll` call

Comment: @Stewart_R 10-4.  I was the one having a brainfart then and just straight up wrong, then.  Sorry.

Comment: @zzxyz Because he isn't asking about why his tasks are not running, we can assume that they *are* running correctly, and he only needs help doing what he actually asked about.  The code he does show makes me think that he at least understands the basics of `async`/`await` and mearly left out a line of example code by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a general standpoint, you can use `.SelectMany` to combine multiple `IEnumerable`s back in to a single `IEnumerable`.

```
var data = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int>{1,2,3},
        new List<int>{4,5,6},
        new List<int>{7,8,9}
     };

var result = data.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Returns: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

---

In your specific example, you probably need to change

```
var apiCallTasks = new List<Task>();
```

to

```
var apiCallTasks = new List<Task<List<JObject>>>();
```

to allow you to access the `Result` property of each individual `Task`, and return the merged results with:

```
apiCallTasks.SelectMany(r2 => r2.Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer, although I prefer Bradley's.  Simple full example although I use ints instead of JObjects.  You might look at `ArraySegment` if performance is an issue.  Neither of our solutions is particularly fast.

```
    private async Task<List<int>> ReturnInts()
    {
        return new List<int> { 5 };
    }

    public async Task<List<int>> PenanceFunction()
    {
        List<Task<List<int>>> tasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>();
        tasks.Add(ReturnInts());
        tasks.Add(ReturnInts());
        List<int> myResults = new List<int>();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach(var t in tasks)
        {
            myResults.AddRange(t.Result);
        }
        return myResults;
    }
```